# Silicone Utensils and Cookware

Tags: utensils

Does using silicone in place of metal, Pyrex or other materials have an impact on food taste?

Comment: I am sorry, but health questions are off topic.  I voted to close, but I think it is better for me to remove the health part so it can stay open.

Comment: Of course, health questions like this one are a little silly in the first place. Materials which are in widespread use in cookware (like silicone, glass, and metals) in the US are regulated by the FDA, so this is not something that you should generally have to worry about.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ I was not aware of that. I apologize. I thought this was an issue of food safety. I would assume discussions of non-stick cookware would also be off limits then.

Comment: We do talk about the issue of not heating PTFE above about 450 F, where it off-gases directly poisonous fumes, which is a safety issue.  But there are no analogous issues with silicone; any effect  that may exist (I don't believe any do) is subtle and long term and thus a health, rather than a safety issue.  At least that is how I look it.

Comment: @MichaelHorwitz Usually, a question like "is there anything that's safe with X but not Y" is okay - for example, with glass versus metal we might point out the risk of shattering by thermal shock. It's debates about "is there a 5% increased chance of some rare disease if you eat your scrambled eggs with a titanium spork" that we want to avoid. I think it'd be fair to edit a food safety angle back into your question, though SAJ14SAJ has probably already answered it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Silicone utensils are extremely nonreactive, and thus do not have any impact on the taste of foods directly.

Like most utensils, if they are cut or abraded, and soil remains, that may affect taste or performance, but that is not inherent to the material itself.